# Registry error when using Selenium webdriver with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, registry

The error occurs when running the [illustrative example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver/v/4.0.0-alpha.1) of Selenium-Webdriver with the latest Chromedriver executable. Chrome is correctly launched but there's an error in the console.

I am using Windows 10.

`run>>regedit>>Chrome`.

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome ::`

I am able to get only this path.

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome::` this path is not availble.

```
2212:9152:0703/185315.194:ERROR:install_util.cc(589)] Unable to create registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome for reading result=2 [2212:196:0703/185315.598:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: 5 [2212:196:0703/185315.598:ERROR:cache_util.cc(134)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\Anchal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\GPUCache to C:\Users\Anchal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000 [2212:196:0703/185315.598:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(169)] Unable to create cache
```

Comment: You've got no code, no tag for a programming language, and no reference to programming. I'm not sure how this is appropriate for SO. If you still think it is, please edit your question and make it clear what you are asking and how it's programming related.

Comment: [2212:9152:0703/185315.194:ERROR:install_util.cc(589)] Unable to create registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome for reading result=2
[2212:196:0703/185315.598:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: 5
[2212:196:0703/185315.598:ERROR:cache_util.cc(134)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\Anchal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\GPUCache to C:\Users\Anchal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000
[2212:196:0703/185315.598:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(169)] Unable to create cache

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions. I've removed all the tags that don't apply to your current question. You need to spend some time editing and clarifying your question. I would suggest that you refer to my comment and [help] for guidance.

Comment: @JeffC the question applies to selenium

Answer (score 6):

**jarmake** posted the solution of this error on github issues:

He made a little tutorial, I'll paste here but if you want the original post, here the [source.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5966)

> 

- Open registry with regedit (just click on Windows start menu and
  start typing regedit, it should come up)
- From the registry explorer, expand HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, and from there
  expand SOFTWARE Expand Policies. I was missing everything from this
  point.
- So what I had to do was to select the Policies by left clicking on
  it, and then right click and from the context menu select New > Key
  and name it Google. Once that is created, select that and right click
  and again select New > Key and name that Chrome.
- Select that folder, and right click. Choose New > String. Name it as
  MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken and leave the value empty.
- If you alreade have Google and Chrome under Policies, I think only
  adding the key as in step 6 should work. I've attached a picture to
  show how it should look like when it's done.
- And just as a clarifier. This is under SOFTWARE/Policies, not
  directly under SOFTWARE.

[image]

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @ctznkane525